# Smallest set of Liner equations, which exactly fit a set of points

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, numerical-linear-algebra, regression, interpolation

I have a set of 2-d points,(it can be of any arbitrary dimension n). I want to find the minimum set of straight lines(linear equations) which exactly passes through the given 2-d points (unlike regression, I dont want any error here).